# Android studio. Parceling data to a specific object in an array list

Tags: android, parcelable

```
package com.example.hussain.assignment4task1;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Image implements Parcelable
{
    private String imageName;
    private String date;
    public ArrayList<Image> images;


public Image(String imageName, String date, ArrayList<Image> images)
{
    update(imageName, date, images);
}

public void update(String imageName, String date, ArrayList<Image> images)
{
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.date = date;
    this.images = images;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = "Image Name: "+ imageName;
    str += "\nDate: " + date;
    return str;
}

/** The following block of code parcels / unparcels data for distribution between activities */

/** Describe the contents in the parcel --
 * interface forces implementation */
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
{
    out.writeString(imageName);
    out.writeString(date);
    out.writeList(images);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Image> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<Image>()
        {
            public Image createFromParcel(Parcel in)
            {
                return new Image(in);
            }

            public Image[] newArray(int size)
            {
                return new Image[size];
            }
        };
/** Private constructor called internally only */
private Image(Parcel in)
{
    imageName = in.readString();
    date = in.readString();
}
}
```

**This is my activity where i insert the image details to be passed to the image in the other activity.**

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.i("IMAGE DETAILS", "Back Button Pressed");
    storeImageDetails(); // to cover half filled forms
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    // need an array list even if we put a single object only
    ArrayList<Image> dataList = new ArrayList<Image>(4);
    dataList.add(image);
    resultIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("IMAGE_DATA", dataList);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    ImageDetailsActivity.super.onBackPressed();  // do not forget
}

/** This method will store all information entered */ 
private void storeImageDetails()
{
    EditText imageNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageNameText);
    EditText dateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
    String imageName = imageNameText.getText().toString();
    String date = dateText.getText().toString();

    ArrayList<Image> dataList = new ArrayList<Image>();

    if (image == null)
        image = new Image(imageName, date, dataList);
    else
        image.update(imageName, date, dataList);

    Log.i("IMAGE DETAILS CHANGED", image.toString());
}
```

I have 4 images on my main activity. clicking on one of them opens up a form where you can enter their details and on back button pressed they sow up below the image themselves only the image name and date. but this shows up the same for all the images. i wanna know how to make it so that only the image that i clicked on gets the details passed to it and not the other images. so separateness passing the data to the individual images is what i wanna figure out.

Comment: an `Image` object contains a list of `Image` child objects?! is that really necessary? did you maybe mean to make that list field static?

Comment: also, in `writeToParcel` you're putting the 3 fields into the parcel, but in the `Image(Parcel in)` constructor you're only reading 2 fields, that's a bug

Comment: oh yeah nah i forgot to change that. the list solution wasnt really necessary and its works without it as well. how do i individually pass data to images ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `public ArrayList<Image> images` field shouldn't be a part of the `Image` class, instead it should be a field in your Main activity.

Try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public ArrayList<Image> images;

    // show images list via adapter or something, and put an OnClickListener on each

    private void onImageClicked(int index) {
        Image image = images.get(index);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE", image);
        intent.putExtra("INDEX", index);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 12345 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int index = data.getIntExtra("INDEX", -1);
            String name = data.getStringExtra("NAME");
            String date = data.getStringExtra("DATE");

            Image image = images.get(index);
            image.update(name, date);
        }
    }
}

public class ImageDetailsActivity extends Activity {

    public void onBackPressed() {
        EditText imageNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageNameText);
        EditText dateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        String imageName = imageNameText.getText().toString();
        String date = dateText.getText().toString();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("INDEX", getIntent().getIntExtra("INDEX", -1)); // return the same index we got from Main
        resultIntent.putExtra("NAME", imageName);
        resultIntent.putExtra("DATE", date);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also just send name+date to the ImageDetailsActivity, without sending an Image object, that way you don't need to implement Parcelable at all

Comment: resultIntent.putExtra("INDEX", getIntent().getIntExtra("INDEX")); // return the same index we got from Main
 this doesnt really work the second parameter. it gives an error saying an integer is needed

Comment: yeah, i forgot to add the defaultValue param, try now